# Uncaught ReferenceError: obj is not defined (загрузка модулей, организация)

Tags: javascript, mvc

Привет. Вот исходная статья  http://webo.in/articles/habrahabr/79-coupling-async-modules/

Вот немного поработал над кодом (изначально он у меня был с рекурсией).

```
<script>
var modules = [
    [0, 'item1', function(){
    alert('item1 is loaded');
    }],
    [1, 'item2', function(){
    alert('item2 is loaded');
    }],
    [1, 'item3', function(){
    alert('item3 is loaded');
    }]
];

/* перебор и загрузка модулей */
function load_by_parent (i) {
    i = i || 0;
    var len = modules.length,
    module;
/* перебираем дерево модулей */
/*
    while (len--) {
    module = modules[len];

    if (!module[0]) {
        console.log(len);
        loader(len);
    }

    }
    */

    for(var j=0;j<len;j++){
        console.log(j);
        loader(j)
        }

}

/* объявляем функцию-загрузчик */
function loader (i) {
    var module = modules[i];
/* создаем новый элемент script */
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
/* задаем имя файла */
    script.src = module[1] + '.js';
/* задаем текст внутри тега для запуска по загрузке */
    script.text = module[2];
/* запоминаем текущий индекс модуля */
    script.title = i + 1;
/* выставляем обработчик загрузки для IE */
    script.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 'loaded') {
/* перебираем модули и ищем те, которые нужно загрузить */
        load_by_parent(script.title);
    }
    };
/* выставляем обработчик загрузки для остальных */
    script.onload = function (e) {
/* исполняем текст внутри тега (нужно тольно для Opera) */
    if (/opera/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        eval(e.target.innerHTML);
    }
/* перебираем модули и ищем те, которые нужно загрузить */
      //  load_by_parent(this.title);

      //?????
      obj.fn();

    };
/* прикрепляем тег к документу */
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}

/* загружаем корневые элементы */
load_by_parent();
</script>
```

Создаю 3 файла
item1.js

```
 alert('item1...load')
    var interface={name:'interface'};
    obj={fn:function(){alert('loaded1')}}
```

item2.js

```
alert('item2...load')
interface.joni=100;
obj={fn:function(){alert('loaded2')}}
```

item3.js

```
 alert('item3...load')
    alert(interface.joni);
    obj={fn:function(){alert('loaded3')}}
```

У меня ошибка **Uncaught ReferenceError: obj is not defined** Я хочу после того как код загрузился - выполнить метод.

Кто знает отличные статьи по организации модулей - помогите, очень прошу.

Comment: извините, если вы не умеете читать (а как иначе объяснить то, что вы задаете этот вопрос, имея на руках совершенно определенное сообщение об ошибке), то как вам помогут ответы, которые (вот сюрприз) тоже нужно читать?

Comment: какие все здесь умные....страшно аж.Зачем ваш комент здесь?Не хочеш помоч так пройди стороной.

Comment: >Не хочеш помоч так пройди стороной

Уважаемый слабограмотный веб-разработчик, а вам не кажется,  что вы сами себе помочь не хотите, если элементарную работу собственного мозга перекладываете на чужие плечи?

ну если уж мой комментарий так задел вашу нежную психику, спрошу по-другому - перед вами сообщение о простейшей ошибке. Что в нем непонятного?

Comment: Элементарную?Мне понятно сообщение,мне не понятно как вызвать метод в динамическом скрипте в тот же момент как только он загрузился.А если вы гуру - подскажите.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> У меня ошибка Uncaught ReferenceError:
> obj is not defined Я хочу после того
> как код загрузился -выполнить метод.

Парсер выдал четкую ран тайм ошибку : "obj" is not defined

Обьект не был задан.
В JavaScript перед использованием переменной нужно (как правило) обьявлять её, хотя бы так : `var object;` - либо глобально либо локально относительно функции в которой находишься.

> Кто знает отличные статьи по
> организации модулей -помогите очень
> прошу.

Про модульные архитекруты на JavaScript? Если да, то есть фреймворки которые уже давно это сделали - например, `backbone.js`

**UPDATE**

`JavaScript The definitive guide Дэвида Фланагана`, уже сильно устарела. (Дата публикации: Ноябрь 2001)В ней не описаны такие понятия как кложуры - `(function(){})()`, `JSON` и еще много вещей которые используются при "модерной" разработки JS приложений. Можно использовать как хороший справочнийк (по `DOM` и стандартным методам) или как руководство для старта. Но не как основное пособие.  <br />
Исходя из своего личного опыта могу посоветовать вот это: (лучшие из лучших на мой взгляд):

1) John Resig - Pro JavaScript Techniques (2006)

2) Jogh Resig - JavaScript Ninja (2012)

3) Nicolas Zakas - JavaScript For Web Developers 3-rd Edition (2012)

4) Douglas Crakford - JavaScript The good parts

**UPDATE 2**
Вместо того чтобы думать, размышлять как устроены модульные и стабильные JavaScript приложения - возьми скачай `backbone.js` посмотри мануал и посмотри как все устроено. Возьмеш пару идей оттуда реализуешь потом самостоятельно на основе стабильной архитектуры что-нибудь свою (на "нативном" `JS`)

Comment: Я создаю переменную var object во внешних скриптах и хочу знать тот самЫй ранний момент когда уже смогу ее использовать.сначала нужно разобратся с нативным js ,а потом братся за фремворки.

Comment: @koza4ok а чтоб

> разобраться с нативным js

нужно хотя бы прочитать *JavaScript The definitive guide*

Comment: Почитай.Тебе думаю тоже будет полезно